# How to get text of an element when mouse over on it it shows text

Tags: javascript, html

Link:- http://galaxyresumes.com/pricing/mid-career/

in link on the left side just below the Resume writing there are "?". If you hover the mouse on it, shows text box. I want to fetch those text. Please help me out. Below is code I tried:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='item_1']//*[@src='http://galaxyresumes.com/wp-content/themes/responsive/images/level_icon.1.png']"));
      //WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html//body//div[3]//div//div//div[3]//form//div//div[2]//div//div//div//div[4]//div//div[2]//div"));
      //Thread.sleep(5000);
      String s = ele.getAttribute("span");
      String s1 = ele.getAttribute("data-original-title");
      String s2 = ele.getAttribute("title");
      String s3 = ele.getText();
      String s4 = ele.getAttribute("text");
      System.out.println(s +"kuki1" + s1 + s2 + "kuki2" + s3 + "kuki3" + s4);
      Actions act = new Actions(driver);
      act.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
      act.pause(10000);
      //Console.WriteLine(Element2ToolTip.text);
      System.out.println(ele.getText() + ele.getAttribute("title")+ ele.getAttribute("data-original-title") +  "kukii");
```

But result is "null".
Please help.

Comment: not get any `?`  in your link

Answer (score 0):

The link you've posted doesn't seem to have any "?". However assuming the hover text is shown in a stadard HTML way and not using jQuery or something, this javascript should get it back :

```
s2 = ele.getAttribute("title");
```

or if it's an image it might be

```
s2 = ele.getAttribute("alt");
```

But .. your code isn't javascript ! looks like Java to me. Wrong tag ?